# React native Firebase ios not supported in latest Architecture

Tags: ios, react-native

I am setting up my react native project and adding firebase. The setup worked fine in Android, but not on ios. On the official docs it is mentioned use_frameworks! is not supported in the latest architecture. Does anyone has a workaround for it? Or its simply not going to work?

official docs - https://rnfirebase.io/

My Podfile -

```
target 'ProjectXYZ' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true


  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    # :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'ProjectXYZ' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

The App crashes on launching.